# CodeIgniter select dropdown box with for loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to create loop  for select box 
for select time start 8.00 and increasing it continusly
for this matter i found solution from
[creating a loop for time incremented by 15 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949035/creating-a-loop-for-time-incremented-by-15-minutes)
but i put it into my code under array it shows only one time 
but i use 
 var_dump($timeinoption)
it shows correctly 
as

```
array (size=1)
  '8 . 0' => string '8 . 0' (length=5)

array (size=1)
  '8 . 15' => string '8 . 15' (length=6)

array (size=1)
  '8 . 30' => string '8 . 30' (length=6)

array (size=1)
  '8 . 45' => string '8 . 45' (length=6)

array (size=1)
  '9 . 0' => string '9 . 0' (length=5
```

but codeignaiter select box not work;

```
form_dropdown('timein',$timeinoption,'8.30');
```

it shows only one time on select box

```
echo form_label('Time Start','timestart');

for ($i = 8; $i <= 17; $i++)
{
  for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j+=15)
  {
    //inside the inner loop
    $opti= $i.' . '. $j;
    $timeinoption=array($opti=>$opti) ;
    }
  //inside the outer loop


}

echo form_dropdown('timein',$timeinoption,'8.30');


     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your array on each loop

```
$timeinoption=array($opti=>$opti);
```

So there will only be 1 value in your array.

Try changing to

```
$timeinoption[$opti]= $opti;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to array inside the loop :

```
$timeinoption = array();
for ($i = 8; $i <= 17; $i++)
{
  for ($j = 0; $j <= 45; $j+=15)
  {
    //inside the inner loop
    $opti= $i.' . '. $j;
    $timeinoption[$opti]  = $opti;
    }
  //inside the outer loop    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy Way to Put loop Dropdown in CI

$d_opt = array(0 => 'DD');

```
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
{
    if(strlen($i)<2)
    {
        $i = 0 . $i;    
    }
    $d_opt[$i]=$i;
}
```

echo form_dropdown('date',$d_opt);

Comment: This does not appear to produce the expected output of 8:00, 8:15, 8:30... that the OP asked for.